# Swagger file security scheme defined but not in use

Tags: api, security, authentication, openapi, swagger-2.0

I have a Swagger 2.0 file that has an auth mechanism defined but am getting errors that tell me that we aren't using it. The exact error message is “Security scheme was defined but never used”.

How do I make sure my endpoints are protected using the authentication I created? I have tried a bunch of different things but nothing seems to work.

I am not sure if the actual security scheme is defined, I think it is because we are using it in production.

I would really love to have some help with this as I am worried that our competitor might use this to their advantage and steal some of our data.

```yaml
swagger: "2.0"

# basic info is basic
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Das ERP

# host config info
# Added by API Auto Mocking Plugin
host: virtserver.swaggerhub.com
basePath: /rossja/whatchamacallit/1.0.0
#host: whatchamacallit.lebonboncroissant.com
#basePath: /v1

# always be schemin'
schemes:
- https

# we believe in security!
securityDefinitions:
  api_key:
    type: apiKey
    name: api_key
    in: header
    description: API Key
  
# a maze of twisty passages all alike
paths:
  /dt/invoicestatuses:
    get:
      tags:
        - invoice
      summary: Returns a list of invoice statuses
      produces:
        - application/json
      operationId: listInvoiceStatuses
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              code:
                type: integer
              value:
                type: string
```

Comment: Your schemes are `https` but your URL's are not, maybe that's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

`securityDefinitions` alone is not enough, this section defines available security schemes but *does not apply them*.

To actually apply a security scheme to your API, you need to add `security` requirements on the root level or to individual operations.

```yaml
security:
  - api_key: []
```

See the [API Keys](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/authentication/api-keys/) guide for details.